# Difference between computing same norm in Banach Space and Hilbert space?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, normed-spaces, banach-spaces

This is another (at least to me!) difficult question I found that I would appreciate some help/insight on:

If B = a real Banach space which is just $C[0,1]\mapsto R$ with elements y = y(x)

and $H$ is a real Hilbert Space $L_{2}[-1,1]$ which is just the completion of the space of continuous functions $C[-1,1]$ with L2 norm $(\|{v}\|)^{2} = \int_{0}^{1}v^{2}(x)dt$

**Question**: given $g(x)$, a continuous function on domain $[0,1]$ and $G$ is just multiplication by $g(x)$, how would I find the norm of $G$ in these two spaces?

I have a general idea that I need to use the operator norm on the first and the l2 norm on the second, but I'm not sure how to actually compute these.

Thank you

Comment: Hello, could you specify the domain and the target space of $G$?

Comment: Hello! Thanks for your comment. I'm pretty sure (even though not explicitly stated) that G domain and target is dependent on the space? If y is in V, G: y ==> g(x)y(x). And if v is in H, G:v ==> g(x) v(x), where v(x) is Lebesgue integrable continuous function on [-1,1]

Answer (score 0):

So the norm of the operator $G$ can be defined by
$$
\|G\|_{B\to B} = \sup_{\varphi\in B} \frac{\|G\varphi\|_{B}}{\|\varphi\|_{B}}.
$$
If $B=C^0([0,1])$, the norm is the $L^\infty$ norm. We can compute for any $\varphi ∈ C^0([0,1])$ the norm of
$$
\|G\varphi\|_{B} = \|g\varphi\|_{L^\infty} ≤ \|g\|_{L^\infty}\|\varphi\|_{L^\infty} = \|g\|_{L^\infty}\|\varphi\|_{B}
$$
Therefore, $\|G\| ≤ \|g\|_{L^\infty}$. But we can take $g=\varphi$ and see that we have equality in that case. Therefore, $\|G\| = \|g\|_{L^\infty}$. The same work if $B = L^2$.